# Android ImageButton OnClick calls another function in the same LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, onclick, onclicklistener, imagebutton

I have got 3 ImageButton in one LinearLayout and the problem is that, when clicked, "@id/yellow" calls the second button function, "@id/green" calls the third button function and "@id/brown" calls its own function instead (how it is supposed to do).

Here is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/yellow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleX="4"
                android:scaleY="2.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="yellowPotted"
                android:background="@drawable/ball_yellow"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/green"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleX="4"
                android:scaleY="2.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="greenPotted"
                android:background="@drawable/ball_green"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/brown"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleX="4"
                android:scaleY="2.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="brownPotted"
                android:background="@drawable/ball_brown"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Here are the 3 functions in my activity (I do not know whether they could be useful):

```
public void yellowPotted(View view) {

    Log.d("BALLS", "YELLOW");

}

public void greenPotted(View view) {

    Log.d("BALLS", "GREEN");

}

public void brownPotted(View view) {

    Log.d("BALLS", "BROWN");

}
```

I have already tried using `setOnClickListener()` and override `onClick()` method in the new `View.OnClickerListener()` directly in the code of my activity, but it does not work either (exact same problem).

Anybody knows what could be the issue?

Comment: What is your issue? Errors? Crash?

Comment: As I wrote, the first two ImageButtons call the wrong functions. I really do not know what is wrong.

Comment: Are your ImageButtons overlapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reproducing your problem. I think it has to do with the scales that you set. I tried your code out with different scales and different backgrounds, it works. Try it out with different scales for the images.

Comment: YES! The scales were the problem! However, I do not really know why they are; do you have an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: @FedericoBacci because the images overlap, and android draws views on top each other. So when you think you're clicking the first button, you're actually clicking the second one because it's on top of the first button

Answer (score 1):

Clean and rebuild your project.

Is most likely an android build/cache issue with the ID's while processing the resources.

Comment: Interesting. The code is running in an activity? The layout is inflated with the setContent() ?

Comment: @skbrhmn found the problem